# Terms for 3 aspects of a function

Tags: functions, terminology

If, for some function $f$ and some value $p\ne 0$, $$\forall x, f(x)=f(x-p),$$ then $f$ is *periodic* and $p$, if $>0$ and minimal, is $f$'s *period*. If, instead, for some values $u\ne 0$ and $v$,
$$\forall x, f(x)=f(x-u)+v,$$
then what is the correct adjective to describe $f$, and what are the correct terms for $u$ and $v$ in relation to this $f$?

The domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The codomain might, but need not, be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; just any group.

---

I have some terminology in mind, but have come to doubt my term for $v$ because (w.r.t. functions) that term is used to denote something else. So I seek other opinions. In the fullness of time I will edit this OP to state the terms I use at the moment, but I want to avoid the situation where people answer "yes, that's OK" (which doesn't *me* any further) and others are put off answering because this question looks to them as if it has a satisfactory answer (which doesn't get future readers any further than I am).

**EDIT:** A staircase function is piecewise constant on intervals of length $u$, so I feel that dxiv's suggestion of "staircase-like function" suggests that the function might be something like that -- that is not my intention. Anyway, the terminology I already knew is that from combinatorial game theory: "arithmetico-periodic", "period" and "saltus". "Period" is of course problematic because of the more specific sense, which is well established. And "saltus" is problematic because of its sense "jump discontinuity".

Comment: Such an $f$ is a periodically perturbed linear function.

Answer (score 0):

Not an authoritative answer by any stretch, but I'd call it maybe "*staircase-like function*", or perhaps "*linearly augmented periodic function*". The latter coming from the observation that $f(ux) - v x$ is in fact periodic: $$\require{cancel}\;f\big(u(x+1)\big) - v(x+1) = f(ux+u)-vx-v = f(ux)+\bcancel{v}-vx-\bcancel{v}=f(ux)-vx\,$$